# Node.js Application stuck on waiting for localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, localhost

I am trying to follow  tutorial where a canvas drawing can be collaborated with various users using Node.js and Socket.io. The following is a source file using to create server. However when I open browser it is stuck on waiting for localhost. What could possibly be the reason?

I tried changing port numbers such that in case that is causing the issue.

```
    // Including libraries

var app = require('http').createServer(handler),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(app),
    static = require('node-static'); // for serving files

// This will make all the files in the current folder
// accessible from the web
var fileServer = new static.Server('./');

// This is the port for our web server.
// you will need to go to http://localhost:8080 to see it
app.listen(4994);

// If the URL of the socket server is opened in a browser
function handler (request, response) {

    request.addListener('end', function () {
        fileServer.serve(request, response);
    });
}

// Delete this row if you want to see debug messages
//io.set('log level', 1);

// Listen for incoming connections from clients
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

    // Start listening for mouse move events
    socket.on('mousemove', function (data) {

        // This line sends the event (broadcasts it)
        // to everyone except the originating client.
        socket.broadcast.emit('moving', data);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Explaining my changes

1. **"use strict"; //good practice**

"Defines that JavaScript code should be executed in "strict mode"." - http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strict.asp

2. **_static = require('node-static');**

Changed variable name static to _static, because static is reserved keyword in strict mode.

3. **request.on('data', function (chunk) {}); //you have to add on ('data')**

That was the main problem, you have to add request.on('data') event or you have to resume after request.addListener('end' ... as @greed said.

4. **var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);**

I changed the location of this line in code, because you have to setup server before use "listen(server)".

```
"use strict"; //good practice
var http = require('http'),
    _static = require('node-static'); // for serving files

// This will make all the files in the current folder
// accessible from the web
var fileServer = new _static.Server('./');

// This is the port for our web server.
// you will need to go to http://localhost:8080 to see it

// If the URL of the socket server is opened in a browser
var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  request.on('data', function (chunk) {}); //you have to add on ('data')

  request.addListener('end', function () {
      fileServer.serve(request, response);
  });
});

console.log("Starting up the server port 4994");
server.listen(4994);

var io = require('socket.io').listen(server); //you have to setup server first so this is the correct place to io.listen
// Delete this row if you want to see debug messages
//io.set('log level', 1);
// Listen for incoming connections from clients
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

    // Start listening for mouse move events
    socket.on('mousemove', function (data) {
        // This line sends the event (broadcasts it)
        // to everyone except the originating client.
        socket.broadcast.emit('moving', data);
    });
});
```

Comment: This could use an explanation of what you changed.  As it stands now, one has to visually compare this to the OP's code to find out what you changed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to resume the request after serving the file.

```
// If the URL of the socket server is opened in a browser
function handler (request, response) {
    request.addListener('end', function () {
        fileServer.serve(request, response);
    }).resume();
}
```